# react and node.js project with express

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I just got an existing project with react and node.js
When I run the react app the server call fails,
the React is on 8080,
the server looks something like this

```
    // Listening on port 3000 for testing and 80 for prodution
app.listen(3000, function () {
  winston.log('info', 'Listening on port 3000!');
});

// Index is currently inactive
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('');
});

// Call and load React
app.get('/app', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/index.html'));
});

// API for Web App
app.use('/api/v1', routes)

// API for Mobile App
app.use('/mapi/v1', mroutes)

// DEFINE ERROR BEHAVIOUR
// =============================================================================

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.status = 404;
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/index.html'));
//    next(err);
});
```

this is how I got the project, I'm assuming it should work, I just need to make the node project somehow to run on port 8080(with the react app)
.
the client request is to localhost/8080(but changes depeneding on the port of the project),
if I'm runing react on 8081 the error will be "can't find localhost 8081/api/v1/GetUsers(example..)" 
the means that the previous developer intended that the server and the client will be on the same port, but I don't how

Comment: What's your question? What does your server call look like? Currently, you're running Node/Express on port 3000, so any calls you make should append the port number. For example, if it's on `localhost`, then a call to your server should be to `localhost:3000`

Comment: You say that making a request to the back end fails, but you include nothing about how the back end call is being made :/

Comment: you're right I just edit